# MySQL error loading data file

Tags: mysql, csv, import

i am trying to execute this query unfortunately i am getting an error ,can anyone tell why this error appear,where i went wrong

**my query:**

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/wamp/www/var/Book1.csv' INTO TABLE contact
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(
@dummy , @dummy , column1, @dummy , column3, column2, @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , column4, @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy
)  ;
```

**Error:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order of `fields...` and the column names:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/wamp/www/var/Book1.csv' INTO TABLE contact
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(
@dummy , @dummy , name, @dummy , nationality, mobile1, @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , twon, @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy
)  ;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer it worked but it insert the cvs data into wrong coloumns in mysql ,example in name its entering the country data in mysql also name,nationality,mobile1 is not inserting into mysql can you tell me why also how to do it

Comment: can you saw my cvs structure

Comment: @Xavi ` @dummy , @dummy , column1, @dummy , column3, column2, @dummy` ... and so on?

Comment: so i should write column1 instead of name?

Comment: @Xavi Yes. That's what i mean

Comment: i tried but it showing error #1054 - Unknown column 'column1' in 'field list'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56454/discussion-between-xavi-and-jens).