# How to insert into selected columns of a table from a csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a csv file with three columns- username, password and email. Now I have a table with columns wp_user, wp_password, wp_email among certain other columns. My question is how to I insert data from the csv file into my table, mapping the three columns and ignoring others?

Comment: Which database system you use?

Comment: @Jens Im using mysql

Comment: @qbr see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464492/mysql-error-loading-data-file/24464525#24464525) maybe this helped

Answer (score 0):

If you'd simply import the csv file into a temporary table called mySourceTable, this would work:

```
INSERT INTO myTargetTable (wp_user, wp_password, wp_email)
SELECT username, password, email FROM mySourceTable
```

Edit2:

For mySQL, load the data into a temporary table using the following command:

```
load data local infile 'source.csv' into table mySourceTable fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(username, password, email)
```

Edit:

Alternatively, you can use the csv file as an external table (for Oracle. Original question was tagged with `plsql`):

> For your CSV file, you'll create a database directory to match your
>   already existing OS directory and grant your Oracle user READ and
>   WRITE access to it: SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_data_dir as
>   '/my/data/dir/'; Directory created.
>
> SQL> GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY my_data_dir TO scott; Grant
>   succeeded.

You then create the external table definition

> Create the external table definition: 
>   CREATE TABLE t1  ( c1 NUMBER, c2 VARCHAR2(30) ) 
>   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
>   ( 
>     default directory
>     my_data_dir
>     access parameters
>     ( 
>        records delimited by newline fields terminated by ','
>     )
>     location 
>     (
>        'report.csv'
>      )
>   );

The resulting table (t1) can then be used in the `INSERT` statement above.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/External_table

Comment: How is copying rows between two tables relevant when trying to import a CSV file?

Comment: @Andomar - Please see my edit, detailing how to add a csv file as an external table.

Comment: @Jens - Please see my edit, detailing how to add a csv file as an external table.

Comment: @SchmitzIT OP is asking for mysql not for oracle.

Comment: @Jens - I could have sworn there was a plsql tag first.

Comment: @SchmitzIT It was wrong tagged by OP after verification OP confirm that is mysql.

Comment: @Jens - Added a mysql solution to load the csv file into a table now.